# AppEngine: missing indexes after restoring backup

Tags: java, google-app-engine, indexing, restore

I am backing up from a Java app to google cloud storage, and then restoring my backup to another Java app.

Everything works ok, but indexes are not rebuilt automatically, so some queries are failing with:

```
Internal Server Error: no matching index found.
```

I never manually created indexes on the original datastore, so I am guessing they are automatically created whenever entities are added, but this is not triggered by the backup process.

Assuming I know which fields of which entities are to be indexed (I can see them from the original deployed app) - **what's the best way to trigger index creation after restoring a backup**?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig), added the datastore-indexes.xml to the app, redeployed, waited for indexes to build and it's now working.

What I am worrying about now is what's gonna happen when I re-deploy to production, is it gonna rebuild all my index even if it's not necessary?

But that's a question for another day, I guess...